# Сохранение истории сообщений

Tags: java, sql, json, spring-mvc

Строю чат на spring mvc, задался вопросом: как лучше реализовать сохранение истории сообщений в чате?

Сейчас у меня сообщения сохраняются прямиком в БД(не душите=)), но так неправильно хотя бы потому что очень длинные тексты просто не поместятся.

Думал создать json файл и в него записывать объекты сообщений, но правильно ли так?

Накидайте вариантов пожалуйста.

Comment: Непонятны проблемы с записью в бд. Что за тексты туда не поместятся? Вы большую советскую энциклопедию в чат отправляете?

Comment: Компилятор ругается, мол слишком длинный текст...

Comment: Хранить историю сообщений в БД это нормально. Компилятор ругается - это в какой момент? Если при компиляции, то до записи в БД еще дело не дошло, ошибка где-то еще. Если приложение падает с рантайм ошибкой "слишком длинный текст..." - надо правильно выбрать тип данных для таблицы, точнее, того столбца, в котором текст сообщения пытаетесь сохранить. Я не знаю, какая у Вас БД, например, в Oracle кроме типа varchar2 с ограничением 4000 байт есть еще типы clob, blob в которые 2ГБ помещаются и туда совершенно точно все помещается - проверено.

Comment: @Kateges Спасибо, то что я и хотел узнать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем сделал следующие выводы: можно использовать БД для хранения переписки т.к это самый простой способ, но есть *примечания*:

- Тип колонки для сообщений должен быть ***LONGTEXT***
- Для *Hibernate* нужна специальная аннотация ***@Lob***

`@Lob` относится к типу данных переменной длины для хранения больших объектов, у неё есть два параметра:

1. *CLOB* - Character Large Object будет хранить большие текстовые данные
2. *BLOB* - Binary Large Object для хранения двоичных данных, таких как изображения, аудио или видео

Указываются они в аннотации `@Column(columnDefinition="СLOB")`, но у меня почему-то не хочет создаваться таблица с таким полем, поэтому я просто оставил `@Lob`.